# get the document html elements in firefox addon

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

I'm creating a firefox extension and I want to get the HTML page elements 
using javascript but the `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` is always giving me an xul objects array.

How can I get the HTML objects array ?

Comment: For clarification: do you want to get references to all the documents on all currently-open pages (tabs, I guess)?

Comment: i want all the html elements in the current page as an array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access the current tab's content from an extension then you need to use `content.document.getElementsByTagName('*')` etc.

Comment: Right. document is the browser document and content.document is the webpage